# Pointers to structures in C++

Tags: c++

In order to complete my homework I had to implement a list in C++, thus I defined a structure:

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node * next;
    Node * operator [] (int index)//to get the indexed node like in an array
    {
        Node *current = this;
        for (int i = 0; i<index; i++)
        {
            if (current==NULL) return NULL;
            current = current->next;
        }
        return current;
    }
};
```

When I used it with actual structures, it worked fine:

```
Node v1, v2, v3;
v1.next = &v2;
v2.next = &v3;
v3.value = 4;
v3.next = NULL;
cout<<v1[2]->value<<endl;//4
cout<<v2[1]->value<<endl;//4
cout<<v3[0]->value<<endl;//4; works just as planned
cout<<v3[1]->value<<endl;//Segmentation fault
```

But when i tried to use it with pointers, the things got messed up:

```
Node *v4, *v5, *v6;
v4 = new Node;
v5 = new Node;
v6 = new Node;
v4->next = v5;
v4->value = 44;
v5->next = v6;
v5->value = 45;
v6->next = NULL;
v6->value = 4646;
//cout cout<<v4[0]->value<<endl; compiler says it's not a pointer
cout<<v4[0].value<<endl;//44
cout<<v4[1].value<<endl;//1851014134
cout<<v4[2].value<<endl;//45
cout<<v4[3].value<<endl;//1851014134
cout<<v4[4].value<<endl;//4646
cout<<v4[5].value<<endl;//1985297391;no segmentation fault
cout<<v6[1].value<<endl;//1985297391;no segmentation fault even though the next was NULL
delete v4;
delete v5;
delete v6;
```

Though it is possible to work with function, I've got some questions:

1. Why the returned value in pointers example was a structure but not a pointer?
2. Why elements now have doubled index and what are the elements between them?
3. Why there was no segmentation fault?

I'd be very thankful if someone explained me these moments or gave me the sources I could learn from

Comment: In the second code snippet you clearly have UB as you used `v1`and `v2`  member `value` without it being initialized. I suggest adding a default constructor to put that value to `0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `v4[0]` (and the rest) aren't actually calling your `Node::operator[]`. That's because `v4` isn't a `Node`, it's a `Node*`, and pointers have a builtin meaning behind `operator[]`: `v4[i] == *(v4 + i)` (that is, we're just indexing into that "array"). So when you write something like `v4[3]`, that isn't calling `operator[](3)`... it's instead giving you back a `Node` three `Node`s after `v4` in memory somewhere, which is basically just garbage.

To get what you want to happen, you'd have to dereference the pointers first:

```
(*v4)[0]
(*v6)[1]
// etc
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! It explains everything as I didn't know about built-in
operator. Does this mean I have no way to change the operator that it would work as I originally wanted to?

Comment: @undocreado You should just not have the operator. It doesn't make sense to provide an `operator[]` for a linked list.

Comment: I wanted to have it because it'll make methods such as elementAt, deleteAt or insert easier to write as i'll just get the indexed member of my first node of list. Is it better to just make some function or write the code for this in every method?

Comment: @undocreado ... which is an operation that doesn't make sense to be supported for a linked list.

Comment: Well that's the task I've got so I need to implement it anyway. So under these conditions what would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

By doing this

```
v4 = new Node;
cout<<v4[0].value<<endl;//44
cout<<v4[1].value<<endl;//1851014134
cout<<v4[2].value<<endl;//45
cout<<v4[3].value<<endl;//1851014134
cout<<v4[4].value<<endl;//4646
cout<<v4[5].value<<endl;//1985297391;no segmentation fault
```

You are not calling operator[] of struct Node, you are making pointer dereferencing, `v4[1]` is equal to `++v4; *v4;` So this code is causing unpredicted behavior, because you are dereferencing some garbage. 
To make it work as you want, you need to change it to:

```
cout<<v4->operator[](0).value<<endl;
cout<<v4->operator[](1).value<<endl;
cout<<v4->operator[](2).value<<endl;
...
```